# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error while running a JAR

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have 3 jars a,b,c A is dependent on B and B has one jar let's call it jar c inside it i.e nested Jar.
Getting error when B is trying to access class of Jar C.
I have added the jar C in the class path of B.

Also when I extract the Jar B I can see that jar C is present inside the extracted folder of B.
But still getting error.

Comment: The standard Java classloaders do not know how to read classes from a JAR file *inside* another JAR file.  Nested JARs don't work.   The second duplink talks about 3rd-party classloaders that solve this problem.